# Can we host Asp.Net Core application as like Web Site Project in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to deploy my **Asp.net Core** application with full of code in IIS server.

So I can able to update individual files in production by just copying new versions to the production server(.cs files or any class file.), or by editing the files directly on the production server.

I do not want to deploy my project code as dll. Instead of dll I want to publish my .cs files same like Web Site Projects.

Comment: Define "full of code", and particularly, why do this instead of compiling the application?

Comment: In case of any emergency bug fixing no need to do in development machine, instead of that I can fix on directly in production.

Comment: This isn't possible, but it has nothing to do with IIS or Kestrel, this is more to do with the fact that the C# code is not compiled.

Comment: Dear Colin, If .Net Core application is supporting as Cross-Platform It should support as like Web Site Projects. So, Hope there is any solution for that.

Comment: That is completely different than what you are asking. IIS can host ASP.NET Core apps, but you want raw source code and not a published application.

Comment: Please see https://forums.asp.net/t/1999901.aspx But I did not get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't do that because IIS acts as proxy for ASP.Net Core

Comment: can we do with Kestrel? even there also IIS acts as proxy.